# PANDAS: Extracting values from a column by applying a condition on other columnns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table

```
 Label   B   C
 1       5   91  
 1       5   65
 1       5   93
-1       5   54
-1       5   48
 1       10  66
 1       10  54
-1       10  15
```

I want only those values in C which are labeled '1' for each set of values in B.I want to extract those values from C in a list like this:
`[[91 65 93],[66 54]]`
Implementing similar thing in python is easy but i want to do same thing using pandas.

Comment: I dont know what is happening  i m not able to put my code here..:( I applied simple 'for' loop on C column and checked if label is 1. Whenever it detects -1 then it will jump to next 1.

Comment: I m able to do it with my code but i want to do similar thing using pandas. I have been trying same thing using DataFrame.groupby. Not successful yet..:(

Comment: Same I am trying. Good problem +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the df to just those values where Label is 1, then on the remaining columns groupby B and get the unique values of C:

```
In [26]:

gp = df[df['Label']==1][['B','C']].groupby('B')
gp['C'].unique()
Out[26]:
B
5     [91, 65, 93]
10        [66, 54]
Name: C, dtype: object
```

You can convert it to a list of arrays also:

```
In [36]:

list(gp['C'].unique().values)
Out[36]:
[array([91, 65, 93], dtype=int64), array([66, 54], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby the Label column, apply the list constructor. Here is an minimal example.

```
Label = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
c = [91, 65, 93, 54, 48, 15]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Label': Label, 'c': c})
df['c'].groupby(df['Label']).apply(list)[1]  # Change 1 to -1 if you want the -1 group
```

If you only want unique entries, then you can do

```
df['c'].groupby(df['Label']).unique()[1]
```

Comment: But column B also puts one restriction. I want only those which are labeled 1 for B=5 and then B=10.

Answer (score 1):

Not so nice as other answers:

first select label and get useful columns:

```
df2 = df[df['Label'] == 1][['B','C']].set_index('B')
```

Then just a list comprehension to get values

```
print [list(df2.ix[index]['C']) for index in set(df2.index)]
```

you get:

```
[[66, 54], [91, 65, 93]]
```